# Cannot compile Common-Qt

Tags: qt, common-lisp, quicklisp

I'm trying to compile Common-Qt using Quicklisp, by executing `(ql:quickload 'qt)`. However, when I try to do so, I get the following error:

`OPERATION-ERROR while invoking #<COMPILE-OP > on
  #<CPP->SO "qt" "so" "commonqt">`

After going to the installation folder, I run `qmake` followed by `make` as suggested [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/#id105941). This fails, with the following error:

`commonqt.cpp: In function ‘void* sw_make_metaobject(void*, char*, int*)’:
commonqt.cpp:263:58: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘const QByteArrayData* {aka const QArrayData*}’ in initialization
         QMetaObject tmp = { { parent, strings, data, 0 } };`

This is followed by a bunch more errors, but this is the one that starts it all. What's going on here and what can I do about it?

Comment: How did you install the qt C++ libraries and headers? Where did you get them and what version are they?

Comment: I'm on Manjaro Linux, so Qt came with it. By the looks of it, it's Qt4, as all the utilities (Qt Assistant, for example) are version 4.8.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you (or ASDF) tries to compile commonQt with QT5. In a shell, try:

qmake -v

This should output the Qt version used. Some distros (I don't know Manjaro Linux) 
install both Qt4 and Qt5 and provide qmake alternatives named qmake-qt4 and qmake-qt5.
So you might want to try to run:

qmake-qt4  commonqt.pro
 make

HTH, Ralf Mattes

Comment: So you mean I have to run ``qmake-qt4 commonqt.pro`` followed by ``make``? Or should it be ``qmake-qt4``, then ``commonqt.pro``, then ``make``?

Comment: First, run qmake-qt4, then make:

    qmake-qt4 commonqt.pro
    make